# Cannot run project after updating Xcode project settings

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Recently I updated my project settings as Xcode recommended. I just pressed a button and they did "everything". However now when I try to run my app on my device it freezes on the loading bar at about 75% and then after 15 seconds it says "build succeeded" but does not run on my device and everything stops as if I had pressed the stop button. I am getting no errors but I am getting the following warnings. It works on the simulator just fine.

For the record I have looked this up and everyone says to add "armv6 or armv7" and I already have this done. I am running deployment target iOS 3.0+

If anyone can help me, it would be appreciated. Thank you!

**EDIT**
Works on my device when I run leaks in instruments... but won't without instruments

[image: Xcode warnings]

[image: Project Settings]

Comment: Quit Xcode, delete your DerivedData folder, and then restart Xcode: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` -- you may find that it magically works again.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick Thanks but no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: In the Target's Summary tab, in the Entitlements section, ensure that "Enable Entitlements" is *un*checked.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't really say much specific here, but if all else fails, I'd try making a new project and copying the content of this project to the new one. This could fix some underlying problems that may have developed in the build settings etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just wondering what the correct way to do this? Xcode seems to be very fussy and unstable when it comes to everything  :/ Thanks

Comment: You would have to do that by hand, i. e. locate this project in the Finder, create a new project in XCode and drag and drop the old project files (except the .xcodeproj file) into the project navigator of the new project. In the window that pops up activate "Copy items[...]" and "Create groups[...]" and the target(s) you need. Oh, and don't delete the old project until the new one is actually working, depending on your success you might want to go back... ;)